# How to fast fill MS Sql 2005 wit data in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert

I crate temporary table in c# (one column, type int), later I want to put ~40 000 values inside (it will be constantly changing). What is the fastest way of doing it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

I would test it first, than look at other solutions.